# MStests through TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, mstest, teamcity

How do you run MStests through TeamCity and the MSBUILD option? Do you put these settings in the main solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure sln2008 runner to start mstest for you.
Another way is to write custom msbuild script that first calls  and than call mstest.exe process. To report generated .trx file please use [TeamCity Service Message](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/MSTest+Support):

##teamcity[importData type='mstest' path='']