# How to create a service message in TeamCity7.1?

Tags: teamcity-7.1

How to create a service message in TeamCity7.1? My requirement is to run test using MSbuild and MS teast in visual studio2012. As I found in [MStests through TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625645/mstests-through-teamcity) if I configure the service meeagses it would help me to get the test results in the report format using xml report processing. To try this I dont know how to set the service mesages and what are the options available for that. If some one can guide me that would help me to solve me the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but in order to generate the service message you just need to output to the stdout stream, using for example a *Command Line* runner with the command "***echo ##teamcity[importData type='mstest' path='']***" in it. That will trigger the generation of the report.

As for the documentation related to using MSTest in TeamCity, you can find the official documentation [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/MSTest+Support).